# NetworkX interactome cluster by color and standardize spacing

Tags: python, python-3.x, networkx

I wanted to cluster nodes by color AND with the same spacing. The image below is what I'd like to achieve:
[image]

The following is what I currently have:

[image]
As you can see, the clusters of nodes don't form semi-circles in the same way like the first image. Is there a way to order the clusters to achieve the same visual as the first image?

The code I'm using to cluster the nodes is:

```
# dictionary that associates each node to a HEX code color (the dictionary is longer in the image I generated, but to give an idea I omitted some)
nodesWithGroup = {'A': '#ffaaa6', 'B': '#ffaaa6',
                  'C': ''#2a0aa1', 'D': '#'#2a0aa1', 'E': '#3b9ef5', 'F': '##3b9ef5', 'G': '#3b9ef5', 'H': '#3b9ef5'}

# clustering nodes by color:  dictionary mapping color to a list of nodes
nodes_by_color = {}
for k, v in nodesWithGroup.items():
    if v not in nodes_by_color:
        nodes_by_color[v] = [k]
    else:
        nodes_by_color[v].append(k)

pos = nx.circular_layout(G)
colors2 = list(nodes_by_color.keys())

# print(colors)
# print(colors2)

angs = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 1+len(colors2))
repos = []
rad = 5.5
for ea in angs:
    if ea > 0:
        repos.append(np.array([rad*np.cos(ea), rad*np.sin(ea)]))

for color, nodes in nodes_by_color.items():
    posx = colors2.index(color)
    for node in nodes:
        pos[node] += repos[posx]

fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 20))
```

Comment: The algorithm used to create your first image is probably hierarchical edge bundling, which is described in this [pdf](https://aviz.fr/wiki/uploads/Teaching2014/bundles_infovis.pdf). The only implementation with python bindings that I know of is in [graph-tool](https://graph-tool.skewed.de/static/doc/draw.html#graph_tool.draw.draw_hierarchy).

Comment: @PaulBrodersen can I use graph-tool's draw_hierarchy in a networkX graph? Could you share an example if possible

Comment: I haven't used graph-tool myself so I would also need to read their docs to figure it out myself. I am just a network visualization enthusiast who has a rough overview over who has implemented what layout algorithm.

Comment: To convert a networkx `Graph` to a graph-tool object, there is [pyintergraph](https://pypi.org/project/pyintergraph/).